# $\sum_0^{\infty}P(n)\cdot z^{-n}$ where $n \in$ perfect squares.

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

There is a sequence, $P(n)$, which is defined only on perfect squares, i-e
$$
P(n) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!} & \quad n \in \{0,1,4,9,16,\cdots\} \\
            0 & \quad otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

$\lambda>0.$

Then how to evaluate the z-transform

$$\mathcal{Z}[P(n)]=\sum_0^{\infty}P(n)\cdot z^{-n}  \quad \quad n \in \{0,1,4,9,16,\cdots\}.$$

Any  suggestion please.

Note that: $P(n)$ is a  squared  Poisson random variable. I know how to calculate the first moment, $E[P[n]]=\sum_0^{\infty}n^2\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}=\lambda + \lambda^2.$

Comment: Doeas rewriting as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{n^2}}{(n^2)!}z^{-n^2}$ help?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Probably not, because then it looks more complicated to be seen as z-tansform.